# Unable to update email activity in Active journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

After the recent SFMC release, we are facing an issue. We are unable to update email activity on an active journey.  The email personalization and email are working fine. No issues. I am just reselecting the same email in the activity and trying to save. We are getting the error "Changes to the message were neither saved or published"[image]

We see this issue for all of our clients. 
Did anyone come across this issue? Any solution?

**Update**
*I have raised a support ticket on this. Below is the response from support.
This issue had been reported to our internal team for investigation. 
I will add your case to the list of cases that are having the same issue. 
It seems that running journeys that were created prior to the APR 2018 release are getting this issue. The message "Changes to the message were neither saved or published." appears when trying to modify the running email.
The workaround is to create a new version of the journey (or copy the journey to another journey). Update the email activity on the new version (or new journey). Activate the journey. 
I will keep you updated on the progress of the investigation. For the moment, please use the above workaround. 
If you have any questions, please feel free to update the case*.*

Comment: I have been having a similar issue. Only solution I have had so far is to create a new version of the journey and reconfigure the email activities you want to update and republish.

Comment: Thanks for the update @TravisNaughton. Support also responded with the same alternate solution.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I'll add it to the Support queue

Comment: I tried to update an email in a running journey and I was able to do that successfully. Please check once again if it's working for you guys now too. @TravisNaughton

Comment: @TravisNaughton yes this issue was fixed by the maintenance updates. apparently the bug was introduced during the April release

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is currently trying to understand how to update a email in a running journey

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_an_email_in_a_running_journey.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_update_multiple_journey_builder_emails.htm&type=5